# Variable Substitution with Bamboo in Dockerfile

Tags: bamboo

My Dockerfile looks like the following:

```
from httpd:${bamboo.test.tag}
COPY index.html /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
```

In `Bamboo` I have a task with the following script:

```
docker build --no-cache -t myproj/my .
```

When running the job, I get the following error:

```
build   26-Sep-2022 10:42:26    Step 1/2 : from httpd:${bamboo.test.tag}
error   26-Sep-2022 10:42:26    failed to process "httpd:${bamboo.test.tag}": missing ':' in substitution
```

How can I substitute the tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a problem with how you are using the dockerfile.

Docker will not expand environment variables inside your Dockerfile. You need to pass the environment value as a build argument in the docker build command then use the ARG keyword inside the Dockerfile.

Your Dockerfile would look like this:

```
ARG IMAGE_TAG
from httpd:${IMAGE_TAG}
COPY index.html /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
```

And you would need to change you docker build command to:

```
docker build --no-cache --build-arg IMAGE_TAG=${bamboo.test.tag} -t myproj/my .
```

[Check a more detailed explanation here](https://vsupalov.com/docker-build-pass-environment-variables/)